# Maximized window with WindowStyle="None" doesn't move again using keyboard SHIFT+WIN+LEFT/RIGHT

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winapi

I have a 2 monitor system under **Windows 7 64 bit .NET 4.5.1**

Here are the window and the steps to reproduce a nasty situation that I have:

xaml of the window

```
<Window x:Class="WindowStyleTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WindowStyle Test"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        WindowStyle="None"
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
  <Grid>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind of the window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // quick fix to show the taskbar, you can remove this, but it also doesn't work
    this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.ThreeDBorderWindow;
    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
    this.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;
  }
}
```

- Move the **maximized** window to other monitor with `SHIFT+WIN+LEFT` or `SHIFT+WIN+RIGHT`
- Now the window should be moved to the other monitor and still maximized
- Try to move the window back to the previous/first monitor with `SHIFT+WIN+LEFT` or `SHIFT+WIN+RIGHT`
- So you wondered why nothing happens? **The window doesn't move again!**
- Me too :-D
- Test system: **Windows 7 64 bit .NET 4.5.1**

[test repository](https://github.com/punker76/WindowStyleTest)

Any ideas to fix this? I think it's a windows issue.

And yes, I need the `WindowStyle="None"`

Comment: The window doesn't move again!

Comment: Calm down, you didn't specify your problem. You just pasted a bunch of repro steps and the code without pointing what is the problem. Don't expect everyone to read and go through your steps to test it for you. You're asking everyone a favor.

Comment: I tried your `XAML` without your codebehind. It works fine for me?

Comment: I only have a single monitor so I can’t reproduce this to get the problem you have. So what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems here. The only problem I can see is the short cut key you are using.

You probably want `WINDOW` + `LEFT` or `WINDOW` + `RIGHT` or `WINDOW` + `UP` to move it.

or `WINDOW` + `SHIFT` + `LEFT/RIGHT` to move between monitors.

Comment: Win+Left/Right only does Aero Snap with subsequent presses moving it to the next monitor (iirc). Using Ctrl probably should just skip to the next monitor immediately.

Comment: yes, sorry you're right. i use the SHIFT+WIN+LEFT/RIGHT keys to move a maximized window to other monitor.